# html img scr no showing

Tags: html, image

I've been putting the following in to a WYSIWYG html view and the image refuses to show up:

```
<img src=“http://evolveddigital.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Google.png" alt="a screencapture of an unpublished media release" height="330" width="623">
```

I only get the text.

I've tried with http, https and just www but nothing is working.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you wrote in editor the complete `<img` tag. Because in question its not showing starting tag.

Comment: note that `“` at the beginning of the source string. Should be a plain `"` double quote. Do not use ms word for coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```html
<img src="http://www.eadt.co.uk/polopoly_fs/1.4709095.1474628177!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_630/image.jpg" alt="a screencapture of an unpublished media release" height="330" width="623">
```

Change `<img src=“http` to `<img src="http`